# How can I decrypt a string which made of a long binary code, each substring represents a number. I'd need the original numbers as a string

Tags: java

"10000001001011010110011000101100100101110001100111111101011111110111100010001111111111001010110111001000110110001010011011010010111111011001101000100010011110100111111110000110110111011001011001100001"

0 -> 0001; 1 -> 0110; 2 -> 1100; 3 -> 0010; 4 -> 1000; 5 -> 1111; 6 -> 1010; 7 -> 0111; 8 -> 1101; 9 -> 1001

If I repleace the substring, I should get the original string but all I got so far is a blank console.

Comment: Please show us your attempted solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a hash map and add for every key (binary value) its value (the "decoded" output number) and then iterate over the whole string to check what binary sets are there.

```
public static String decode(String binary)
    {
        StringBuilder decodedValue = new StringBuilder();
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("0001", "0");
        map.put("0110", "1");
        map.put("1100", "2");
        map.put("0010", "3");
        map.put("1000", "4");
        map.put("1111", "5");
        map.put("1010", "6");
        map.put("0111", "7");
        map.put("1101", "8");
        map.put("1001", "9");
        for (int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i = i + 4)
        {
            String current = binary.substring(i, i + 4);
            decodedValue.append(map.get(current));
        }
        return decodedValue.toString();
    }
```

**Sample Test**

```
String testCode = "10000001001011010110011000101100100101110001100111111101011111110111100010001111111111001010110111001000110110001010011011010010111111011001101000100010011110100111111110000110110111011001011001100001";
output: 40381132970958757445526824846183589633767541889110
```